Consistent parametrization of solutions to any subset of a family linear equations
Informally, my question is under which conditions it is possibly to consistently parametrize the solutions to any subset of a family linear equations.
Specifically, consider a (possibly infinite) family of vectors $(a_i)_{i \in I} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with the property that for any finite $J \subseteq I$ we have
$$\dim \bigcap_{j \in J} a_j^\bot = \max\{n - |J|, 0\} \,.$$
In other words, $\{a_j\}_{j \in J}$ is linearly independent. Alternatively we could also drop this condition which allows $I$ to be possibly infinite.
My question is whether or when there exists a consistent parametrization for solutions of various subsets of this system of liear equations.
Specifically, does there exist a family of bases $\{B_J\}_{J \subset I, |J| < \infty}$ such that $B_J$ is a basis of $\bigcap_{j \in J} a_j^\bot$, which is consistent in the sense that
for finite disjoint $J_1, J_2 \subseteq I$ one can obtain $B_{J_1 \cup J_2}$ in a "natural" way from $B_{J_1}$ and $B_{J_2}$?
For example, the best possible result would be that $B_{J_1 \cup J_2} = B_{J_1} \cap B_{J_2}$ is possible.
Example: If $(a_i)_{i \in I}$ is an orthogonal system vectors then  this is possible. Since $\bigcap_{j \in J} a_j^\bot = span((a_j)_{j \not\in J})$ we can choose $B_J = \{a_j\}_{j \not\in J}$ and obtain $\{a_j\}_{j \not\in J_1} \cap \{a_j\}_{j \not\in J_2} = \{a_j\}_{j \not\in J_1 \cup J_2}$.
